# Не получается добавить запись в таблицу PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

При выполнении следующего кода

```
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);//Глухова

$db->query("INSERT INTO clients (Фамилия, Телефон) VALUES ($lastname, $phone)");
```

Выдаётся ошибка

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Глухова' in 'field list'

При этом, если добавлять в таблицу, указывая только поле Телефон с переменной $phone, всё нормально.

Вот код html

```
        <form action="./db/add_client.php" method="post">
            <h1 class="h3 fw-normal">Клиента с таким номером телефона нет, добавьте, клиента</h1>

            <div class="form-floating mt-3">
                <input name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control text-center" id="floatingInput" placeholder="+79127532435" value=<?php echo $phone?>>
                <label for="floatingInput">Номер телефона</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mt-3">
                <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                <label for="lastname">Фамилия клиента</label>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-4" type="submit">Добавить</button>
        </form>
```

Вот структура таблицы
[image: Структура таблицы]

Comment: Зачем вы делаете htmlspecialchars? Эта функция нужна для вывода html, а не для записи значений в базу данных. В базу данных надо записывать данные как есть, а чтобы избежать [sql-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) используйте [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Колонки, по-сути, имеют строковый тип, а вы, если распечатаете запрос, увидите, что вставляете просто значения. Строковые значения надо вставлять в кавычках. В данном случае вокруг каждой переменной в запросе должы быть **одинарные** кавычки

Comment: $phone у меня тоже формата string, однако, если кидать только эту переменную, всё добавляется без ошибок

Comment: То, что она типа string -ничего не значит. Она строковая, можно сказать, для php, для sql - это просто "данные". Для sql - строка - то, что обёрнуто в кавычки. В данном случае их нет ............ и кстати `htmlspecialchars` тут не нужны совершенно

Comment: @Руслан просто телефон состоит из цифр и MySQL понимает, что это не имя таблицы. Есть много тонкостей насчёт того как парсится запрос во всяких неочевидных случаях. Чтобы не гадать как будет работать запрос и не бояться использовать ключевые слова, удобно имена таблиц всегда заключать в апострофы, а строки в одинарные кавычки.