# Данные из формы не вносятся в базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Мне надо, чтобы данные из формы переносились в таблицу в MySQL. Код написал, как в видео, перед этим сделал БД 'test' с таблицей 'users', внутри которой 3 столбца: 'id', 'name' и 'age'. При заполнении данных в форме по идее должен вылезать текст - при удаче "Успешно!", при ошибке - "Извините, возникла ошибка на сайте", но ни того, ни другого не выскакивает после нажатии на кнопку "отправить", хотя в видео вылезал текст об успехе, ну и соответственно, ничего не заполняется в БД, она остается пустой. В чем может быть проблема?
На первом скриншоте я под этими данными захожу в бд, на втором как выглядит бд, куда я пытаюсь внести данные, а на третьем скрине сама таблица с данными для заполнения.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get">
    <label>Введите свое имя:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />

    <label>Введите свой возраст:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Отправить" />
  </form>
  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['formSubmit'])) {
    $nameform = $_GET['name'];
    $ageform = $_GET['age'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    if ($mysqli->connect__errno) {
      echo "Извините, возникла проблема на сайте";
      exit;
    }
    $name = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($nameform) . '"';
    $age = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($ageform) . '"';
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ($name, $age)";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($result) {
      print('Успешно!' . '<br>');
    } else {
      print('Не успешно');
    }
    $mysqli->close();
  }
  ?>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается добавить запись в таблицу PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471928/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-php)

Comment: Судя по коду, вполне логично, что нет ни одного сообщения, потому что подключение к БД у вас проходит без проблем, а вот запрос завершается, скорее всего, с ошибкой. Попробуйте дописать else и там вывести, например, "НЕ успешно", тогда станет понятно, что ошибка действительно в запросе.

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev, сделал, как вы посоветовали. Теперь при открытии странички с формой сразу же вылезает ошибка "не успешно", хотя я даже ничего не вводил, просто обновил и все. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Обновите php код в вопросе, сейчас посмотрим.

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev, изменил, но немного не так выразился в прошлом комментарии: я перезапустил OSPanel и заходя на страницу с формой, ошибки нет. Но после внесения данных и отправки она появляется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался со своим вопросом. Видимо, ошибка была в таблице. Я задал столбцу "id" индекст "PRIMARY" и поставил галочку в пункте "A_I", а также поменял кодировку БД на `utf8mb3_general_ci`.