# Кнопка из формы перенаправляет в PHP файл

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку submit, данные из формы заносятся в базу данных, а вместе с этим открывается файл form.php, который как раз отправляет данные в БД. Я попытался написать скрипит на JQ, закинул туда preventDefault, а внутрь засунул ajax-запрос, но проблема осталась: при нажатии на кнопку перенаправляет на пустую страницу (form.php). Также, по задумке, при успешной отправке формы в БД должен вылезать alert с "Успешно!", но этого не происходит. Я думаю, что проблема в ajax запросе, но мне не хватает знаний. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Код формы:

```
<form class="popup__form" method="get" name="form">
              <input
                class="popup__form-text popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Ваше имя"
              />
              <input
                class="popup__form-tel popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="tel"
                name="tel"
                placeholder="Номер телефона"
              />
              <input
                class="popup__form-email popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Электронная почта"
              />
              <input
                class="popup__form-submit popup__form-input popup__form-button"
                id="#btn__submitForm"
                type="submit"
                name="popup-submit"
                value="Отправить заявку"
              />
            </form>
```

Код form.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['popup-submit'])) {
      $nameform = $_GET['name'];
      $telform = $_GET['tel'];
      $emailform = $_GET['email'];
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dudich");
      if ($mysqli->connect__errno) {
        echo "Извините, возникла проблема на сайте";
        exit;
      }
      $name = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($nameform) . '"';
      $tel = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($telform) . '"';
      $email = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($emailform) . '"';
      $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, tel, email) VALUES ($name, $tel, $email)";
      $result = $mysqli->query($query);
      $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

Код JQ:

```
$('#btn__submitForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'form.php',         
        method: 'get',             
        dataType: 'html',     
        success: function(data){   
            alert('Успешно!');          
        }
    });
})
```

**UPD:**

JQ:

```
$('.popup__form-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'form.php',         
        method: 'get',           
        dataType: 'html',     
        success: function(data){   
            alert('Успешно!');           
        }
    });
})
```

button:

```
<form
              class="popup__form"
              method="get"
              name="form"
              action="form.php"
            >
              <input
                class="popup__form-text popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Ваше имя"
              />
              <input
                class="popup__form-tel popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="tel"
                name="tel"
                placeholder="Номер телефона"
              />
              <input
                class="popup__form-email popup__form-input popup__form-fields"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Электронная почта"
              />
              <button
                class="popup__form-submit popup__form-input popup__form-button"
                name="popup-submit"
              >
                Отправить заявку
              </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: У вас просто не происходит того события, которое вы прописали в jQ. Вы поставили обработчик подтверждения КНОПКИ. Кажется, подтверждать нужно отправку формы....

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть не

```
$('#btn__submitForm').submit(function(e){
```

а

```
$('.popup__form').submit(function(e){
```

т.к. событие отправки происходит именно **формы**, а не кнопки. У кнопки происходит лишь клик. Не смотря на то, что у неё стоИт тип `submit`, это не говорит о том, что на неё происходит событие сабмита, а то, что она ответственна за сабмит формы

---

*P.S.* Если идёт работа через ajax, то вообще зачем у кнопки стОит тип `submit`? Можно сделать обычную кнопку и отправлять данные по клику на неё

Comment: Сначала я сделал так, как вы посоветовали, но результат тот же. Далее я поменял по вашему совету кнопку и сделал её по-человечески, добавив button и убрав тип submit. В JQ я закинул класс кнопки и вместо submit поменял на click, но результат такой же - открывает пустую страницу php. Я добавил UPD в вопросе внизу, чтобы вы могли увидеть изменения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так?

Comment: `<button type="button" ...`

Comment: @syrex тег `<button>` **по умолчанию** тоже имеет тип `submit`, так что там придётся писать тип `button` :)) Вот такая вот глупость... кнопка с типом кнопка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поменял на тип button, но теперь не отправляются данные(
Тут наверное уже конфликт с php кодом? Потому что у button есть name = "popup-submit", который присутствует в в условии в php коде. Что посоветуете?

Comment: @syrex  "не отправляются данные" - с фронта js или из php? Посмотреть уходят ли  данные на бэкенд - можно в консоли разработчика в браузере (который по F12 открывается). и смотреть вкладку Network........ Для просмотра что не так на бэке - влючают показ ошибок и используют отладку (можно смотреть все ответы в данном топике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482 ), аналогично есть для js  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482  ....тоже можно увидеть попадает ли вообще что-то в код...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сначала хочу сказать что я невнимательный) Зайдя в консоль, сразу понял что JQ код был просто не виден из-за подключения....Я это исправил. Теперь, при нажатии на кнопку страница не обновляется и не перенаправляется, а ещё выскакивает alert, как и планировалось. Во вкладке network я заметил, что при заполнении данных и нажатии на кнопку "отправить", появляется файл form.php со статусом 200, Но заходя в БД данные не вносятся. Почему? ведь статус 200 - это успешно, разве нет? 
скриншот: https://imgur.com/a/SgUoH4X

Comment: @syrex 200 означает что php скрипт успешно отработал, но это не значит что не было каких-либо неточностей например в sql запросах. Для этого надо отдебажить и посмотреть что с ними не так....ещё. как я писал, включить отображение ошибок.... и в том же ответе от сервера их можно будет увидеть, даже при ответе 200 если могут быть какие-то warnings или notice.... ну а корректность запросов надо смотреть в отладке как минимум....например вместо `VALUES ($name, $tel, $email)` надо будет писать `VALUES ('$name', '$tel', '$email')`   .... причина: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1471929/191482